# connector acceptor pattern

Tags: design-patterns

From where I can get link to connector acceptor pattern explained simple ,and also a sample code .
The one I get   [cs.wustl.edu](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Acc-Con.pdf)  , I find difficult to understand.

Answer (score 6):

In simple words; in a distributed system, once a service is initialized, this design pattern decouples connection establishment and service initialization. Acceptors, connectors, and service handlers helps in achieving the decoupling.

1> Connector establishes a connection with a remote acceptor component and initializes a service handler to process data exchanged after the connection is made.

2> Acceptor passively waits for connection requests from remote connectors, establishing a connection upon arrival of a request, and initializing a service handler to process data exchanged after the connection is made.

3> Initialized service handlers perform application-speciﬁc processing and communicate via the connection established by the connector and acceptor components.

You can find some easy explanation in this link -
http://kurser.iha.dk/ee-ict-master/tiardi/Slides/ARDI3-POSA2-AcceptorConnector.pdf

Comment: That's what confused me in the original document, as well: _"1> Connector establishes a connection with a remote acceptor component"_, _"2> Acceptor [...], establishing a connection"_ So, there are two connections between 2 end points. Isn't that one too many? Furthermore _"1> [...] initializes a service handler"_, _"2> [...] initializing a service handler"_  Figure 2 on page 3 shows the _ServiceHandler_ to be an intermediate entity of an m:n relationship. According to my understanding the service handler**s** that are mentioned  in _1>_ and _2>_ is just one, is the same. Right?